# Random Forest with less samples & variation in test_scores

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm building a RandomForestRegressor with 75 samples. The distribution of y (After train_test_split) is as below. (Blue-Train and Red-Test)

[image]

Keeping `test_size=0.3` (hold out) and doing a `GridSearchCV` on the training set, and initializing a new model using the resulting `best_params_`, I get a test score of `0.83` on the hold out set.
[image]

But when i run this a second time (another random test, train split), the accuracy goes down to even as low as `0.35`. I repeated the score check (R^2) 100 times for this model, below is its distribution.

```
sco =[]
for i in range(0,100):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.30)
    score = best_grid.score(X_test,y_test)
    sco.append(score)
sns.histplot(data=sco)
```

Assuming that the outliers caused the R2 to vary like this in test set, i decided to remove the outliers (dataset drops to 66 samples) and retrain the model. Below is the `distribution` of target `y` after outliers removed.

[image]

However following the same steps as above for model, the score drops even further, strangely to `0.20`. Iterative run of score check shown below. For most of the tests, the R2 stays below 0.5.

[image]

Any Idea why the decline ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that these "outliers" which you removed were not really the problem, maybe there were in fact easier to predict then the more common cases and increased $R^2$ significantly, and that is why your performance has declined after removing them. Or there could be any number of other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You have 75 samples which is not enough data for meaningful machine learning. The result is high variance in performance between different runs.